# object.once method in Backbone.js not working

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

According to the Backbone [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-once) you can use:

```
object.once(event, callback, [context])
```

as an alternative to:

```
object.on(event, callback, [context])
```

when you want to fire an event only once to a certain object

Why does the following not work:

```
app.aCollection.once("reset", function() {
    console.log("not working");
});
```

but this does:

```
app.aCollection.on("reset", function() {
    console.log("working");
});
```

Notice the subtle difference with once and on.
The error I get tells me the object has no `once()` method.
`aCollection` is a Backbone.js collection object.

**How do I get the `once()` method working?**

Comment: `once` was added in the latest Backbone version (http://backbonejs.org/#upgrading) . Are you sure you are on 0.9.10 ?

Comment: Good point. Just updated, was still on 0.9.2. Problem solves itself. Working in a dev environment right now. There could be a reason why we are not working with the newest version here.. but we'll see about that later :) Thanks!